# AFNetworking 2.0 not parse xml

Tags: ios, xml, afnetworking-2

I want to read a response from a web service.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer=[AFXMLParserResponseSerializer new];
[manager GET:@"http://openapi.aibang.com/search?app_key=f41c8afccc586de03a99c86097e98ccb&city=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC&q=%E9%A4%90%E9%A6%86" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

But I only got `<NSXMLParser: 0x15d85490>` from Xcode log. It's not the right xml response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EN: Because the `responseObject` is a `NSXMLParser` instance, you can't treat it like string!
You have to implement `NSXMLParserDelegate` to handler the xml parser progress!

CN: responseObject返回的是NSXMLParser实例，你必须实现NSXMLParserDelegate协议才能处理该xml字符串！骚年! :-)

solution 1: use NSXMLParser to parser

```
[manager GET:@"http://openapi.aibang.com/search?app_key=f41c8afccc586de03a99c86097e98ccb&city=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC&q=%E9%A4%90%E9%A6%86" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
    [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
    XMLParser.delegate = self;
    [XMLParser parse];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

solution 2: use GDataXML to parser (much easier)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"http://openapi.aibang.com/search?app_key=f41c8afccc586de03a99c86097e98ccb&city=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC&q=%E9%A4%90%E9%A6%86" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:responseObject encoding:0 error:nil];
   NSLog(@"%@",doc.rootElement);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: 谢谢。我决定还是尽量用json吧，xml看起来好麻烦。

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct, on iOS there is only the [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html) which is a sax parser and you will need to implement the sax parsing.
The object returned in the block is an instance of  [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html) and that is what you see in your log statement, with object you parse the data returned from the HTTP request. The passing it self is handled with the [`NSXMLParserDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

If you want DOM parsing, you could use the [ONO XML](https://github.com/mattt/Ono) parser, it is made by on of the developers of `AFNetworking` and it a DOM Parser.
And Of course there is nice integration with `AFNetworking`:[`AFOnoResponseSerializer`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOnoResponseSerializer)

Comment: I've only used it once, I prefer JSON, but yes it did everything you would expect. Including XPath and perfect integration with AFNetworking.